# Replace string in a file by matching pattern obtained from another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have two files

**File1:**

```
$node_(17) set X_ -0.31
$node_(16) set Y_ 1274.64
ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(17) setdest -0.31 1274.64 0.00"
ns_ at 2.1 "$node_(16) setdest 2041.48 295.29 2.52"
```

**File2:**

```
(17) (0)
(16) (1)
```

I want to find first column values(of File2) in File1 and replace them with corresponding 2nd column values. E.g. (17) in File1 should be replaced with (0), (16) with (1).

**Output File1:**

```
$node_(0) set X_ -0.31
$node_(1) set Y_ 1274.64
ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(0) setdest -0.31 1274.64 0.00"
ns_ at 2.1 "$node_(1) setdest 2041.48 295.29 2.52"
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -f <(sed 's/\((.*)\) \((.*)\)/s|\1|\2|/' file2) file1
```

Output:

```
$node_(0) set X_ -0.31
$node_(1) set Y_ 1274.64
ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(0) setdest -0.31 1274.64 0.00"
ns_ at 2.1 "$node_(1) setdest 2041.48 295.29 2.52"
```

If you want to edit file1 "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect for small files. For large files it gets too slow. Is it possible to do using Perl?

Comment: I assume it is possible in Perl too. Please, start a new question.